# Removing a Mysql type Quote from the list

Tags: list, coldfusion, expression, cfml

I have a list and i need to remove the quote from the list, any build-in function or custom function available for removing the mysql type quote from the list. Here is the list

```
`BODY`,`BY`,`CREATED`,`DEPARTMENT_ID`,`ID`,`MODIFIED`,`PARENT`,`PRIORITY`,`STATUS`,`SUBJECT`,`UPLOADS`
```

Comment: Solved it by using ListDequalify from using the cflib.org library, Just needs to add the #chr(96)# to it which makes it eligible for backticks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ListDeQualify](http://www.cflib.org/udf/listDeQualify) looks like a lot of work if you just need to strip out the ` characters.  Why not simply use [replace()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Replace):

```
<cfset mylist = "`BODY`,`BY`,`CREATED`,`DEPARTMENT_ID`,`ID`,`MODIFIED`,`PARENT`,`PRIORITY`,`STATUS`,`SUBJECT`,`UPLOADS`">
<cfset mylist = replace(mylist, "`", "", "ALL")>
```